# Subquery in FROM clause using CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I need to implement `select` `from` a nested query, for the sake of simplicity let it be:

```
select * from (select * from city) c
```

How can this be done using `CriteriaQuery` and `Subquery`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, your syntax is not JPA compliant as mentioned previously, secondly, you must know that subqueries in JPQL are allowed only in WHERE and HAVING clauses.  The same applies to Criteria queries. If you need the more powerful SQL subquery features then with JPA you have to use JPA provisions for native queries, or otherwise, use another type of JDBC library.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because (select * from city) is not an entity and CritieriaAPI queries on entities not on tables.

The only way would be to create a view for (select * from city) and map that view to an entity.